# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence python,numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to study python. but this error makes me sad. If anyone knows that error, please tell me why...
code is

```
data_vec = []
data_vec_sp = []
for i in range(0,len(data_ham)):
    for j in range(0,len(data_ham[i])):
       data_vec.append(np.ndarray.tolist(model.wv[data_ham[i][j]]))
for i in range(0,len(data_spam)):
    for j in range(0,len(data_spam[i])):
       data_vec_sp.append(np.ndarray.tolist(model.wv[data_spam[i][j]]))
lengths = []
for i in range(len(data_ham)):
    lengths.append(len(data_ham[i]))
lengths_sp = []
for i in range(len(data_spam)):
    lengths_sp.append(len(data_spam[i]))
max_seq=max(lengths+lengths_sp)

dataX = []
for i in range(len(lengths)):
    total = sum(lengths[:i])
    dataX.append(data_vec[total:total+lengths[i]])
dataY = []
for i in range(len(data_ham)):
    dataY.append([['0']])
for i in range(len(lengths_sp)):
    total = sum(lengths_sp[:i])
    dataX.append(data_vec[total:total+lengths_sp[i]])
for i in range(len(data_spam)):
    dataY.append([['1']])

processed = np.array(dataX,dtype = "f")
***Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.***
```

dataX is word vectors
such as

> > > dataX[0][0]=
> > >       [-0.1615869700908661, -0.3353504538536072, -0.05911640822887421, 0.2664419412612915, 0.23376771807670593, 0.013697666116058826, 0.08846186846494675, 0.023173419758677483, 0.23772063851356506, 0.003773996140807867, -0.1691707819700241, 0.4130796790122986, -0.0094629917293787, 0.2146264612674713, 0.2039080709218979, 0.09040140360593796, 0.14459063112735748, -0.12667202949523926, 0.33783870935440063, 0.006472950801253319, 0.26460835337638855, 0.13737431168556213, 0.04874108359217644, 0.17068377137184143, -0.13585394620895386, 0.1331317275762558, 0.15738724172115326, 0.32112088799476624, -0.5897336006164551, -0.21117675304412842, -0.07932453602552414, 0.2983131408691406, -0.14773669838905334, -0.11435408890247345, 0.013958614319562912, 0.27606719732284546, -0.1857372522354126, -0.3181498646736145, 0.671415388584137, -0.029171733185648918, -0.19198976457118988, -0.24715560674667358, 0.20854316651821136, 0.10005248337984085, -0.2556343376636505, 0.1531827747821808, 0.023028111085295677, 0.1619538813829422, 0.13868877291679382, 0.20250250399112701, 0.06268277019262314, 0.08580871671438217, 0.06232626363635063, -0.014056061394512653, 0.0780516192317009, -0.24966590106487274, -0.013334897346794605, 0.3877508044242859, 0.09984628856182098, 0.2474772036075592, -0.016906747594475746, -0.17072062194347382, 0.10843656957149506, 0.15756770968437195, 0.06598909944295883, 0.017902569845318794, -0.549013614654541, 0.21266651153564453, 0.031236575916409492, 0.050672244280576706, 0.27269500494003296, -0.252864271402359, 0.3161967992782593, -0.04220119118690491, 0.10098162293434143, -0.45764288306236267, 0.31370213627815247, 0.3360774517059326, -0.21591132879257202, -0.20584052801132202, 0.13033269345760345, 0.2552568316459656, -0.15911956131458282, 0.18036118149757385, -0.09493415802717209, -0.021795518696308136, 0.3608446717262268, 0.03977162763476372, -0.19157318770885468, -0.24235652387142181, -0.1861632615327835, 0.0054754409939050674, -0.3136100769042969, -0.0009150459081865847, -0.11295150965452194, 0.29373738169670105, 0.09046965092420578, 0.18789909780025482, 0.32259559631347656, -0.10442658513784409]

Comment: The error usually means that your list input has non-conforming shape to a 2d (or nd-) array. Arrays are always rectangular in numpy: each row is the same size. Check that your nested list contains lists of all the same length at every level of nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing just one element of `Xdata` doesn't help much, except to suggest that it is a triply nested list.

I'll try to recreate something simpler.  Note that a couple of the sublists are shorter:

```
In [371]: dataX=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2],[3,4]]]
```

With sublist differences `np.array` creates an object array:

```
In [372]: np.array(dataX)
Out[372]: 
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), list([4, 5, 6])],
       [list([1, 2]), list([3, 4])]], dtype=object)
```

If I force it to create a numeric array, it gives your error:

```
In [373]: np.array(dataX,dtype=int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-373-29c5879a94b0> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(dataX,dtype=int)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```